# How to explain this special relativity asymmetry? Why does the ship but not the trip get Lorentz contracted in the star's frame of reference?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames

I thought this was paradoxical, but in light of the comments and answers I guess I should downgrade it to a plain old dumb question.

I haven't got a proper argument, just a lack of understanding, I guess. It just seems that the situation looks kind of symmetrical, but not for the change of distance.

When a rocket initially at rest at the earth accelerates to close to the speed of light in a vacuum, taking one second in the earth frame to do so, towards a star that is ten light years away in the earth frame, the Lorentz contraction causes the star in the rocket frame to be only about a light week away from the rocket, as well as flattened to a thin disk, and moving toward the stationary rocket at close to the speed of light, with the star clock ticking about a thousandth as fast.

In the frame of reference of the star, the star is stationary, and the rocket is now moving towards it at just below the speed of light, flattened to a disk 1/1000 as long as the rocket before acceleration, but *still ten light years away*, not about a light week away. Why does the Lorentz contraction only shorten the rocket and not the journey? Why isn't the rocket, in the star frame, a light week or so away from the star?

Edit: I think I figured it out, sort of, maybe. The symmetry I was looking for is maybe there, but you need to look at the frame of the rocket, and postulate an asteroid at rest in the rocket frame that is passing the star.

In the earth-star frame the asteroid is passing the star at the same time as the rocket is passing the earth, and the separation is ten light years. But this length is the Lorentz contracted version of the space between the rocket and the asteroid as exists in the star-earth frame. So the length of that space in the rocket-asteroid frame must be 707 times longer, i.e. 7070 light years. Right?

It's a sort of 7070 light year fast moving ladder momentarily inside a ten light year barn with both doors shut at the same time.

So the question "Why is ship contracted but not the trip?" really misses the mark. It maybe should be, "Does the space around the ship also get contracted?" and the answer seems to be "Yes". But it it gets/got contracted *before* it got to be ten light years, down from 7070 light years.

Shoot me down in flames if I am still confused.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138112/discussion-on-question-by-matthew-christopher-bartsh-how-to-explain-this-special).

Answer (score 2):

All of these geometric properties of Minkowski space have simple analogs in Euclidean space. Imagine, in the Euclidean plane, a straight strip and a curve that is parallel to it then bends to meet it:

```
_______
       \
        \
         \
##################
```

You can draw perpendiculars to the horizontal lines and perpendiculars to the diagonal line that are meant to represent "planes of simultaneity":

```
.    .    .    .                     .
_______   .    .         _______  .
.    . \  .    .               .\      .
.    .  \ .    .            .    \  .
.    .   \.    .         .       .\
##################       ##################
.    .    .    .           .
```

You can see that the distance from any point to the strip along the diagonal dotted lines is longer than the distance along the vertical dotted lines. You can work out from the Pythagorean theorem that it's longer by a constant factor of $\sqrt{1+m^2}$, where $m$ is the slope of the diagonal line. The similarity to the $\sqrt{1-v^2}$ factor in special relativity is not a coincidence.

Your question amounts to asking why, at the point where the curve changes direction, the distance to the strip as measured along the vertical lines doesn't suddenly change. It's hard to answer that sort of question because the answer depends on why you expect it to change in the first place. Perhaps I could answer that it doesn't change because the distance measured along those lines is a continuous function of position. But I think you don't need my answer. Come up with your own explanation of the Euclidean problem that makes sense to you, then use the same explanation for the Minkowskian problem, because the underlying reason is the same.

Comment: "You can work out from the Pythagorean theorem that it's longer by a constant factor of 1+m2−−−−−−√, where m is the slope of the diagonal line. The similarity to the 1−v2−−−−−√ factor in special relativity is not a coincidence". 1+m2 has a plus but 1-v2 has a minus. That doesn't seem very similar. Did you mistype it?

Comment: What do you think of my analysis of where I was going wrong in the comments attached to the question? I like your typed diagrams. Haven't seen them in a physics or math context. Did you type them by  hand? It would be great if I could relate them to Minkowski diagrams. I've never understood the math of quantum mechanics, and I fear it may be the same with Minkowski diagrams. I don't like it when the axes move. I feel that axes should stay put. lol. Also, it should be a2 + b2 = c2 with not minus signs.

Comment: @Matthew I thought from our chat sessions that you understood that some signs get changed from `+` to `- ` when going from Euclidean geometry to Minkkowski geometry. Or didn't that stuff actually make sense to you?

Comment: @PM2Ring It didn't compute at all. I mean, I couldn't make sense of it. Way, way above my head. Math is not my strong suit. I remember you saying that, though. "Time has a different character" I think you said.